# nodejs mongoose model / relations questions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I recently discovered nodejs + mongodb (via mongoosejs).
I am coding a small app for my raspberry to display a scoreboard on a big led pannel.

I actually have 2 problems

To configure the scoreboard for a match I need :

2 teams : each teams has n players ( 1 to .... )
A time limit
A goal limit
the goals scored by each team

Here is my models files :

```
var MatchSchema = new Schema({
        teams: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }],
        goals_left: Number,
        goals_right: Number,
        time_limit:  Number,
        goal_limit: Number
    });


var TeamSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Team Name is required"],
        },
    players: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player' }]

});

var PlayerSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Player Name is required"],
    }
});
```

Question 1 :

- Create team : I have no problem to insert in my Teams collection an array of player object ( I use checkboxes to select the players of the team )
- Create match : I can't manage to insert an array of 2 team objects in my match collection, here is the form and the controller action :

Form

```
div.row.form-group
            each i in [0,1]
                div.col
                    label(for='teams-'+i) #{ i===0 ? 'Left' : 'Right' } Team
                    select.form-control(type='select' id='teams-'+i placeholder='Select TEAM'+i name='teams['+i+']' required='false' data-target='/team/new')
                        option(value=null) Select #{ i===0 ? 'Left' : 'Right' } Team
                        for team in all_teams
                            option(value=team._id) #{team.name}
```

Create match code :

```
// Handle Match create on POST.
exports.match_create_post =  [
    (req, res, next) =>  { 
        if(!(req.body.teams instanceof Array)){
            if(typeof req.body.teams==='undefined') {
                req.body.teams=[];
            }else{
                match_teams=new Array(req.body.teams);
            }
        }
        next();
    },
    (req, res, next) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        // Create a team object with escaped and trimmed data.
        var match = new Match(
            {
                //teams: [  "5a92f691d5038fd56c648664", "5a92fa14b4d7f5d665da9ef4"],
                teams: match_teams,
                time_limit: req.body.time_limit,
                goal_limit: req.body.goal_limit,
                status: req.body.status
            }
        );
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            res.render('match_form', { title: 'Create Match', match: match, errors: errors.array()});
            return;
        }  else {
            match.save(function (err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                res.redirect(match.url);
            });
        }
    }
];
```

The weird thing is I do the same thing for creating a team and it works perfeclly...
I can not understand why req.body.teams is undefined

Question 2 :

If I manually insert the 2 teams in my teams fields like :
teams: [  "5a92f691d5038fd56c648664", "5a92fa14b4d7f5d665da9ef4"]

When I want to display match detail :

Controller Query :

```
exports.match_detail = function(req, res, next) {
    var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);

    async.parallel({
        match: function(callback) {
            Match.findById(id)
                .populate('teams')
                .populate('teams.players')
                .exec(callback);
        },

    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (results.match==null) {
            var err = new Error('Match not found');
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }
        // Successful, so render
        res.render('match', {
            title: 'match Detail',
            match: results.match
        } );
    });

};
```

The team names are correctly displayed but for player details I only can access the _id, not the name

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Thank you

Clément

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the collection, 1st record was inserted mannually : https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnuhwi6hy89vasi/Screenshot%202018-03-02%2010.06.21.png?dl=0

Comment: I believe you may be creating a new object with `var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);`. Try passing `req.params.id` directly into your find function. So something like `Match.findById(req.params.id)`